# Fill triangle with 3 color gradient in Java

Tags: java, graphics, gradient

I was not able to find a solution for this problem.
I would like to paint a filled triangle in Java with gradient where each corner has different color. Something like this:

[image]

I found some posts online but I was not able to figure out how to do the gradient in Java. The problem is that in Java you can do GradientPaint only from one color to another, which is not suitable to fill a triangle.

So far I have come up with this code which does not work as expected:

```
triangle.p1().getValue();
Color color1 = calculateColor(triangle.p1().getValue());
Color color2 = calculateColor(triangle.p2().getValue());
Color color3 = calculateColor(triangle.p3().getValue());
Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
Polygon polygon = new Polygon(
        new int[]{(int) triangle.p1().x(), (int) triangle.p2().x(), (int) triangle.p3().x()},
        new int[]{(int) triangle.p1().y(), (int) triangle.p2().y(), (int) triangle.p3().y()},
        3);
GradientPaint gradient1 = new GradientPaint(
        (float) triangle.p1().x(), (float) triangle.p1().y(), color1,
        (float) triangle.p2().x(), (float) triangle.p2().y(), transparent);
GradientPaint gradient2 = new GradientPaint(
        (float) triangle.p2().x(), (float) triangle.p2().y(), color2,
        (float) triangle.p3().x(), (float) triangle.p3().y(), transparent);
GradientPaint gradient3 = new GradientPaint(
        (float) triangle.p3().x(), (float) triangle.p3().y(), color3,
        (float) triangle.p1().x(), (float) triangle.p1().y(), transparent);
graphics2d.setPaint(gradient1);
graphics2d.fill(polygon);
graphics2d.setPaint(gradient2);
graphics2d.fill(polygon);
graphics2d.setPaint(gradient3);
graphics2d.fill(polygon);
```

Here is the result I am getting: [image: points A and B have the same color but the triangles adjacent to AB have different color]

Some threads that mention similar thing:
[Triangle Gradient With Core Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388033/triangle-gradient-with-core-graphics) and [Java 3 Color Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771575/java-3-color-gradient)

Comment: What is the problem do you have? You have a good explanation, even some example code. Are there any errors? Is your code (please post some) not working? Or are you stuck at one specific detail? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I updated the description of problem and added some code.

Comment: What is the result you get with this code, could you please add a screenshot of the current result? (My guese would be that its interpolating to white in the middle of the triangle?)

Comment: Anyway, thank you stranger for downvoting perfectly reasonable question. You are the best!

Comment: Alright, first I think all your colors are green. Meaning if you want multiple colors (blue and red) you need to fix the first part (where you call `calculateColor(triangle.p1().getValue());`. Second, your gradient vector/direction is incorrect. Right now every gradient points from one corner to the next corner following the direction of the triangle border, instead of pointing to the center of the opposite line following the median. It will still give a nice effect, though I think not what you are looking for.

Comment: @matomato it's a perfect reasonable question for me too, I upvote. By the way, did you find the answer yet? I would like to see the code, I can achieve this triangle in GLUT or GLFW or any OpenGL library but I wonder how it's done in Java or GDI or JS Canvas (not WebGL).

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the idea that if you pick any color inside the triangle it will create three areas from the three points of the triangle. Therefore we are extendng the principle of linear interpolation

```
color=(distance to p1)/(distance p1, p2)*c1+(distance to p2)/distance(p1, p2)*c2;
```

to the 2-D plane. Thus the weighting coefficents will be areas:

```
public int areaTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
  return (int)(0.5*Math.abs((x1-x3)*(y2-y1)-(x1-x2)*(y3-y1)));
}

BufferedImage b=new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Polygon pl=new Polygon();
pl.addPoint(100, 100); pl.addPoint(200, 150); pl.addPoint(150, 200);
Rectangle r=pl.getBounds();
int a=areaTriangle(pl.xpoints[0], pl.ypoints[0], pl.xpoints[1], pl.ypoints[1], pl.xpoints[2], pl.ypoints[2]);
int[] c1={255, 0, 0}, c2={0, 255, 0}, c3={0, 0, 255};
for(i=0; i<r.width; i++)
for(j=0; j<r.height; j++)
  if(pl.contains(r.x+i, r.y+j)) {
    int ix=r.x+i, jy=r.y+j;
    int a1=areaTriangle(ix, jy, pl.xpoints[0], pl.ypoints[0], pl.xpoints[1], pl.ypoints[1]);
    int a2=areaTriangle(ix, jy, pl.xpoints[0], pl.ypoints[0], pl.xpoints[2], pl.ypoints[2]);
    int a3=areaTriangle(ix, jy, pl.xpoints[1], pl.ypoints[1], pl.xpoints[2], pl.ypoints[2]);

    int[] c=new int[3];
//      for(l=0; l<3; l++) c[l]=(int)((1-1.0*a1/a)*c1[l]+(1-1.0*a2/a)*c2[l]+(1-1.0*a3/a)*c3[l]);
    for(l=0; l<3; l++) c[l]=(int)((1.0*a1/a)*c3[l]+(1.0*a2/a)*c2[l]+(1.0*a3/a)*c1[l]);
    b.setRGB(ix, jy, 0xff000000|(c[0]<<16)|(c[1]<<8)|c[2]);
  }
```

If you try the commented line you will get the three complementary colors.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old question, still the issue has not been satisfactorily answered.

The problem is that there is no appropriate `java.awt.Paint` implementation that supports interpolating color within a triangle where colors are given at the triangle vertices. This is a common thing in computer graphics (rasterization) where barycentric coordinates are used to determine the mixing weights for a point within the triangle (see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec14.pdf section 3.5.1).

Since I also could not find any implementation of such a Paint implementation for `java.awt.Graphics2D` around the web, I implemented it myself. You can find it here (titled `BarycentricGradientPaint` ): https://gist.github.com/hageldave/391bacc787f31d2fb2c7a10d1446c5f6

A screenshot for reference, notice how the second triangle is partially transparent and edges are anti-aliased. AA is realized through a 4x MSAA approach.

[image: screenshot of the demo of the paint implementation]